# Structure for Classes containing Lists of Instantiated classes to be stored in Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, class, dictionary, structure

For my example classes to be stored are lets say:

```
class Race
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Competitor> Competitors = new List<Competitor>();
}

class Competitor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Stats> SomeData = new List<Stats>():
}

class Stats
{
   //Other Properties Etc
}
```

They are to be stored in :

```
class Events : Dictionary<string, List<Race>>
{             
    public Events()
        : base()
    {
    }              
}
```

And I fill the Dictionary with another class :

```
class GenerateEventsData
{
    public Events newEvents = new Events();

    public GenerateEventsData()
    {
        fillEvents();
    }

    private void fillEvents()
    {
        //Method to fill events.
    }
 }
```

I feel as though I'm getting to a stage where lists of classes are being stacked up and my structure is not correct.

I plan to eventually serialize the data to disk and re-use at a later date but that's beyond the bounds of this question. However if the classes aren't well structured i think i may have issues.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not using a database?

Comment: Your right I can use a database. I'm just trying to learn different aspects of the language for fun more then anything. And struggling with getting my head around structuring my classes for different scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a generic container:

```
public class ListDictionary<T> : Dictionary<string,List<T>>
{
    public ListDictionary():base(){}

    public void AddItem(string key, T value)
    {
        if(ContainsKey(key))
             this[key].Add(value);
        else
             Add(key,new List<T>{value});
    }

    //similar for remove and get
}
```

Also have a look at the repository pattern.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @BlaineWordly actually added a link to a sharepoint thing... http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/ is much better